# Getting parameters values from url ../en/rings-4#/page-2 -> Prestashop 1.6.1.15

Tags: php, pagination, prestashop-1.6, url-parameters

Prestashop pagination uses #/page-n url.
How to get page number using header.tpl ?
I need it in order to get a next/prev page documentation.

Comment: The hash part of the URL is not even send to the server - you only have access to it using client-side scripting.

Comment: You'll have to parse yourself. Make use of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) . you'll be able to access the parameters from `fragment`.

Comment: As Cbroe wrote, $_SERVER does not include the url parameters. So, there is no way to parse and access the parameters using header.tpl.

Comment: Prestashop included $p variable to know the page number. Now using this friendly #page-n url the $p variable always is equal to 1.